# Cannot run Spring Boot project with Sentry 5.0.1

Tags: java, spring-boot, sentry

I created a simple spring-boot project with `Sentry 3.1.0` version. It worked fine. Now as soon as I bumped the version to `5.0.1` the project won't start and gives the following error stack trace:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-06-21 17:56:26.287 ERROR 74330 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:163) ~[spring-boot-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:577) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) [spring-boot-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) [spring-boot-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) [spring-boot-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) [spring-boot-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332) [spring-boot-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at com.bijay.springbootsentryexample.SpringbootSentryExampleApplication.main(SpringbootSentryExampleApplication.java:11) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:104) ~[spring-boot-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:450) ~[spring-boot-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:199) ~[spring-boot-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:182) ~[spring-boot-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:160) ~[spring-boot-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    ... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'io.sentry.spring.boot.SentryAutoConfiguration$HubConfiguration$SentryWebMvcConfiguration': Unexpected exception during bean creation; nested exception is java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy
```

I've scanned through `Sentry` docs but couldn't find a solution to this issue. Can anybody tell me what did i do wrong?

Github link for the project is [here](https://github.com/bijay-shrestha/springboot-sentry-example)

**If You'd like to reproduce**
Just bump the verison of `sentry-spring-boot-starter` from `3.1.0` to `5.0.1` in `pom.xml` and run the project.

Will really appreciate your help.
Thank you.

Comment: I raised a GitHub issue: https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-java/issues/1546

Comment: The fix for this issue has been submitted https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-java/pull/1552. At the moment as a workaround, you can either add Spring Security Core to your dependencies (and exclude Spring Security from Spring Boot autoconfiguration) or exclude `SentryWebMvcConfiguration` autoconfiguration and replicate it in your custom config class. Ideally - please wait for the bugfix release. I am sorry for inconvenience

Comment: Sure. Thanks @MaciejWalkowiak -- will be waiting for the fix.